# Negoteation not working

Tags: c++, netbeans

I can't show you all the code, 'cause it is large but I can show example of the stuff that I'm trying to use. So, code is the following:

```
namespace TestNamespace {
    struct TestBase
    {
        TestBase(std::string _id = "") : id(_id) {}
        std::string id;
    };


    struct Test : public TestBase
    {
        Test(std::string _id = "") : TestBase(_id), b1(true), b2(true) {}        
        bool b1;
        bool b2;
    };

    typedef std::list<Test> Tests;

    struct SomeStatesHolder
    { 
        SomeStatesHolder() : tests(), someAdditionalVar(true), someAdditionVar2(2222) {}
        Tests tests;
        bool someAdditionalVar;
        int someAdditionVar2;
    };
}

class WorkingClass
{
public:
    WorkingClass() : m_someStatesHolder(new TestNamespace::SomeStatesHolder()) {
        TestNamespace::Test t("id1");
        m_someStatesHolder->tests.push_back(t);
    }

    TestNamespace::Tests getTests() const { return m_someStatesHolder->tests; }
    bool getB1(const std::string& id) const {
        const auto fnd = std::find_if(m_someStatesHolder->tests.cbegin(), m_someStatesHolder->tests.cend(), [&](const TestNamespace::Test& t){
            return t.id == id;
        });
        return (fnd == m_someStatesHolder->tests.cend()) ? true : fnd->b1;
    }
        bool getB2(const std::string& id) const {
        const auto fnd = std::find_if(m_someStatesHolder->tests.cbegin(), m_someStatesHolder->tests.cend(), [&](const TestNamespace::Test& t){
            return t.id == id;
        });
        return (fnd == m_someStatesHolder->tests.cend()) ? true : fnd->b2;
    }

private:
    TestNamespace::SomeStatesHolder *m_someStatesHolder;
};
```

But deep in the project in function of yet another class I have lines:

```
qDebug() << "\n\n\n\nTESTS: "
         << workingClass.getB1("id1") << ":" << !workingClass.getB1("id1") << " "
         << workingClass.getB2("id1") << ":" << !workingClass.getB2("id1");

const auto tests = workingClass.getTests();
const std::string fid = "id1";
const auto fnd = std::find_if(tests.cbegin(), tests.cend(), [&](const TestNamespace::Test& t){
    return t.id == fid;
});
 qDebug() << "\nTESTS2: "
         << fnd->b1 << ":" << !fnd->b1 << " "
         << fnd->b2 << ":" << !fnd->b2;
```

And the output of that lines is:

```
TESTS:  true : true   true : true
TESTS2:  true : true   true : true
```

What could be the reason of such a strange behaviour? Why **!** didn't work? I should admit, that

- this stranges are in **Linux**, **OSX**. In **Windows** everything is fine
- new similar test stuff works fine (like this), but my particular struct in project - not.

**UPD1:** I also tried to make functions for getting those values, result the same. Code like this also not working:

```
qDebug() << "Test3: " 
         << workingClass.getB1("id1") << ":" 
         << !((bool)workingClass.getB1("id1")) << ":"
         << !workingClass.getB1("id1") << ":"
         << (!(workingClass.getB1("id1")))

bool AAAAA = workingClass.getB1("id1");
qDebug() << "Test4: " 
         << AAAAA << ":" 
         << !((bool)AAAAA)) << ":"
         << !AAAAA << ":"
         << (!(AAAAA))
```

Comment: Can you try add some paranthesis to make sure evaluation is correct: qDebug() << "\nTESTS2: "
         << (fnd->b1) << ":" << (!(fnd->b1)) << " "
         << (fnd->b2) << ":" << (!(fnd->b2));

Comment: Yes, look at UPD1

Comment: Hmm, maybe your qDebug object has bugs. Some code that fails on linux...

Comment: No, qDebug() - is logging from Qt. I used it just to show the problem. The point is negoteation not working. In my project I have something like func(!workingClass.getB1("id1"));

Comment: qt can have bugs, and your compiler can have bugs too. maybe try print as integer: << (int)(!AAAAA) << (int)(AAAAA) << (int)(!(int)AAAAA)

Comment: it gives me kind of "112 : 113   58 : 59". I also tried (int)(!true) which gave me 0. So, it's a compiler bug?

Answer (score 1):

`std::find_if` will return `last` if nothing is found, which points **after** the last element `std::list`. That is memory garbage, that you are returning with `return fnd->b1`.

When you negate this memory garbage, the last bit will be negated, thus you end up with *112 : 113 58 : 59* when casting it to int.

Comment: I skipped all the checkings of such stuff, so this definitely not a problem

Comment: @user2123079 How do you do the check?

Comment: if (fnd == tests.cend()) {/* no value found */ }

Comment: @Sven Nilsson Correct, I was just asking how OP does it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem. In my project in a same class (SomeStatesHolder) my bool values wasn't initialized in constructor list.

ps: use damn  **-Wreorder** or even better **-Werror -Wall**